# Is their any possibility for appium setup in Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2012?

Tags: appium

I just want to know, is their any possibility to have appium setup in Windows 2008 and Windows Server 2012???

Please let help me know if anyone knows above the setup in sever2008 or 2012.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We run tests on 'Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard' and it works great.